# How can i add current date at the end of the title in javascript datatable?

Tags: javascript, datatable

How can i add current date at the end of the title?
I want to display file name when export it like: excel_22.03.22

```
  $('#example').dataTable({
               
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        title: 'Excel',
                        text:'Export to excel'
                        //Columns to export
                        //exportOptions: {
                       //     columns: [0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
                       // }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        title: 'PDF',
                        text: 'Export to PDF'
                        //Columns to export
                        //exportOptions: {
                       //     columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                      //  }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace title: 'Excel' with something like this

use dayjs

title : `Excel${dayjs().format(YY.MM.DD)}`